# Python and Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I already had a python 3.8 version and i was using Vs code ,but now i had to download anaconda and jupyter notebbok.As the normal installation steps are i did that but whenever I TRY TO RUN MY JUPYTET NOTEBOOK by giving command  Jupyter notebook an anaconda prompt ,I get the following errors:
**Should i uninstall python which already exixts on my pc so that anaconda and jupyter works properly and because of uninstallation of my python software will my VS code stop working?**I need both the softwares tbh.**PLEASE HELP :([**ERRORS WHILE RUNNING JUPYTER NOTEBOOK**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox3XB.png)**

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall the current python.When do you face this issue
if you are facing this issue when trying to open jupyter notebook through command promt try opening it with anaconda.

Comment: i didn't understand